# Calling same function from different sources causes different output? How?

Tags: java

I have a basic function that loads a file and returns a "URL safe" base64 string.

```
public void getDocumentFromDMS() {
    DMS_Handler dms = new DMS_Handler();
    // Get the document using the DMS library
    dms.getDocument();
    // Convert Document to Base64
    // TODO for now get the document from the project
    try {
        InputStream documentInputStream = new FileInputStream("Doxis.pdf");
        byte[] documentBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(documentInputStream);

        // Map information to IPP
        String base64Document = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(documentBytes);
        base64Document = URLEncoder.encode(base64Document, "UTF-8"); // This class contains static methods for converting a String to the application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIMEformat
        documentData.put("base64Document", base64Document);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(documentData.entrySet().toArray()));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If I call it from my JUnit test works perfectly and the image url is correct.

Starts like `[base64Document=iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAACU`

```
    public void testDocument() {
    DocumentHandler docHandler = new DocumentHandler();
    docHandler.getDocumentFromDMS();
}
```

But if I call it once deployed in Tomcat

```
[base64Document=JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MNCg0KMSAwIG
```

And I can't see the image on the page.

**I debugged and `documentBytes` has different bytes at `byte[] documentBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(documentInputStream);`.**

**How is this possible? It's the same file. Perhaps encoding?**

Comment: any idea what is?

Comment: You're using a relative pathname, so what file is found and read depends on the working directory of the process, which is probably different. Your first data is actually the beginning of a png image; why on earth are you naming a file .pdf when it is actually png?